# I messed up my /.bash_profile and Bash will not recognize most commands

Tags: terminal, bash

I was trying to add paths to my `~/.bash_profile` and accidentally screwed up the final one right when I closed it. Now, I cannot use a majority of the basic shell commands, like `ls`, `touch`, etc. I can still use `echo` and `cd`. When I `echo` my path, I get: `“/Users/Forthman/Desktop/paml/bin:??`. If I try other commands, I get: `-bash: touch: command not found`.

My `~/.bash_profile` is invisible, and so I cannot directly open it in TextWrangler or TextEdit. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Open TextWrangler. Press the command key and o key. A dialog box will open.
Press the shift key, the command key and the period key and your dot files will be visible in the dialog box.